# Custom allocators with clang++ v4 and gcc 6.3 libraries

Tags: c++, clang, c++14

I'm running into a great deal of trouble using custom allocators with clang++ 4.0.0, on a system (arch linux) where the libraries come with gcc 6.3.1.  Here is a minimal non-working example:

```
#include <string>

struct myalloc : std::allocator<char> {
  using std::allocator<char>::allocator;
};

struct mystring 
  : std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, myalloc> {
  using std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, myalloc>::basic_string;
};

int
main()
{
  mystring r = "hello";
  mystring s (std::move(r));
}
```

My intent here is obviously for `myalloc` to be a custom allocator that behaves exactly the same as the system `std::allocator`, and `mystring` to be the same as `std::string` except that it uses `myalloc`.  This should be the least likely scenario to cause problems.  (Obviously once this is working I want to customize the allocator further.)

The code compiles cleanly with `g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -Werror`, but `clang++ -std=c++14` fails with:

```
In file included from strerror.cc:1:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.1/../../../../include/c++/6.3.1/string:52:
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.1/../../../../include/c++/6.3.1/bits/basic_string.h:477:9: error: 
      no matching constructor for initialization of
      'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
      myalloc>::_Alloc_hider'
      : _M_dataplus(_M_local_data(), std::move(__str._M_get_allocator()))
        ^           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
strerror.cc:7:8: note: in instantiation of member function
      'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
      myalloc>::basic_string' requested here
struct mystring 
       ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.1/../../../../include/c++/6.3.1/bits/basic_string.h:109:2: note: 
      candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'typename
      std::remove_reference<allocator<char> &>::type' (aka
      'std::allocator<char>') to 'const myalloc' for 2nd argument
        _Alloc_hider(pointer __dat, const _Alloc& __a = _Alloc())
        ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.1/../../../../include/c++/6.3.1/bits/basic_string.h:107:14: note: 
      candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires
      1 argument, but 2 were provided
      struct _Alloc_hider : allocator_type // TODO check __is_final
             ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.1/../../../../include/c++/6.3.1/bits/basic_string.h:107:14: note: 
      candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires
      1 argument, but 2 were provided
1 error generated.
```

Is this just a bug in clang or gcc's libraries, or is there something conceptually wrong with my code?

Comment: Why do you derive from `basic_string`? Should your custom string not just be `using mystring = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, myalloc>`?

Comment: I need to add a couple of constructors to my real string class and just simplified for the example.

Comment: nothing in the standard insists that basic_string must be inheritable...

Comment: @RichardHodges Shouldn't all classes be inheritable unless otherwise specified?  The word inheritable doesn't even seem to appear in the C++14 standard.  So unless you have a private virtual superclass with only non-public constructors or some other edge condition covered by other access control concepts in the standard, where does the standard even support the notion of non-inheritable classes?

Comment: @user3188445 Classes can be `final`

Comment: @Barry Yes, I'd forgotten about that.  Still, if the spec doesn't say a class is final, why wouldn't it be reasonable to assume it is inheritable?  Especially classes that pre-date C++11.

Comment: @Barry https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/derivation#4

Comment: @T.C. Oh I know, I was just answering the question "where does the standard even support the notion of non-inheritable classes?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimal fix for your minimal example is to add this member to `struct myalloc`

```
template<class> struct rebind {
    using other = myalloc;
};
```

Of course best is not to inherit from std::allocator (in that case you won't need rebind), and not to inherit from string either,  those classes are not intended as public bases.